# Get week of quarter using Date object

Tags: javascript, date

How to get the **week of quarter** using `new Date()`?

For example 9/27/2019, we're in Q3 and last week of month so therefore `weekOfQuarter = 13`.

Assume ISO8601 format of week: Monday through Sunday.

Comment: How are you defining week 1 of your quarter? First Monday of that quarter?

Comment: Was Monday 31 December, 2018 in the last week of 2018 or the first week of 2019?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fully tested for possible edge cases, but ... seems to work

```js
const date = new Date('2019-09-27T00:00:00Z');
const startOfQuarter = new Date(date);
startOfQuarter.setUTCDate(1);
const month = startOfQuarter.getUTCMonth();
startOfQuarter.setUTCMonth(month - month%3);
const dowOfFirstDayInQuarter = (startOfQuarter.getUTCDay() - 1) % 7;
const daysToFirstMondayInQuarter = (7 - dowOfFirstDayInQuarter) % 7;
const daysSinceFirstMondayInQuarter = parseInt((date - startOfQuarter) / 86400000, 10) - daysToFirstMondayInQuarter;
const weekOfQuarter = parseInt(daysSinceFirstMondayInQuarter / 7, 10) + 1;
console.log(`week of quarter = ${weekOfQuarter}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer is based on first Monday in quarter. I've updated my question to include clarification of definitions.

Comment: isn't that what you wanted? week of QUARTER = 13 ... yet your "clarification" suggests the answer you want is 6?? The "clarification" also suggests that 1 sep 2019 is week 1 of the month, yet it's ALSO week 5 of August, is it not? therefore you'd be counting weeks twice